# Repairing ACL on Windows drive

Tags: windows, ntfs, acl, dualboot

Few days before I installed Ubuntu MATE edition. System was very unstable and crashing so I deleted it, but before that something weird happened.

Im tried to access one pdf file located on Windows 10 system partition, on different drive. Mounting option are unchanged, defaulty for Ubuntu 22.04. I sucesfull read file and some time after i tried rebooting into Windows 10. Without success. Windows just hang on booting screen. I'm booted older Windows 7 instalation and found that Windows 10 partition is listed but unaccessible (Windows 7 cannot even check partition size). But chkdsk /f /v /b /r doesn't found any problem, however very long processed files security descriptions.
Partition is also accessible from linux. I also tried some restore options at boot time (F8) but all failed because cannot accessing any file including restore points.

So I guess that Ubuntu messing with ACLs on Windows 10 partition. I stored most data on different drives anyway, but want to bring back system with installed programs. Is there any way to fix Windows ACL or restoring it to defaulty values?

Edit. My pendrive, also used with Ubuntu, also had permisions problems.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't monkey with Windows permissions, as it doesn't really understand them. You have a more serious problem. Question: Is Windows 10 the only operating system installed on the problematic disk/drive?

Comment: Agree with @harrymc - this feels like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: It's not possible for Ubuntu to change the NTFS permissions of a drive.

Comment: @Ramhound: The `ntfs-3g` Linux NTFS driver has had read/write support for NTFS permissions for at least 13 years now. Though it's not _usually_ enabled by default (and OP says mount options were not changed), but it would also not surprise me if it ended up active accidentally...

Comment: @user1686 - I am aware of read-write support.  Ubuntu didn't chang the author's file permissions.